# Notifications for completed Time Machine backups?

Tags: time-machine, catalina

Is there a way to enable notifications for completed Time Machine backups?

Comment: I can't imagine anything more irritating than 24 "success" notifications a day.

Comment: I only run a backup once every 10 days.

Comment: I can't imagine the reasoning behind doing that, but OK.

Answer (score 2):

With [TMNotifier](https://tmnotifier.com/) you can send yourself an email when a backup is completed. It also notifies you when a Time Machine error occurs.

The only disadvantage: *TMNotifier* is not free.

However, there is a *free version*, but you can only do limited things there... But the small price that has to be paid, it's worth it!

Comment: Can it only notify upon completed backups? Screening over the options, it seems to be always sending on failures as well.